# how to call java script function of other jsp page script function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to call JavaScript function on `index.jsp` from `file.jsp` here is my code  after getting the value in index.jsp script function then I want to call servlet from inside those function

this is my index.jsp

```
<%@page import="org.apache.catalina.connector.Request"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" %>
<html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
           function popuponclick()
           {
              var mywindow=window.open("file.jsp", "file","status=1,width=350,height=150");
           }
           function onLoadById(long id)
           {
              after getting value call the servlet GetEmployeeServlet passing id as a parameter
           }
           function onLoadByname(String name)
           {
              after getting value call the servlet GetEmployeeServlet passing name as a parameter
           }    
     </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form name="form1">

    <%String name11=request.getParameter("name"); 
    out.println(name11);%>
        <% if(name11!=null){
            out.println(name11);
            session.setAttribute("EmployeeById","1");}
        %>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"  onclick="popuponclick()" value="GetEmployeeById" name="name"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="GetEmp" value="1"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"  onclick="popuponclick()" value="GetEmployeeByname" name="name1"></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my file .jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml"%>
<%@page
    import="com.nousinfo.tutorial.employee.service.model.bo.EmployeeBO"%>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script>
function myfuntion()
{
    var d=document.getElementById('first');
    var c=document.getElementById('second');
    alert(window.parent);
    window.close();
    }
</script>
</head>

<bod>

<% if (session.getAttribute("EmployeeById")!=null) {
    session.removeAttribute("EmployeeById");
%>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>GetEmployeeByName</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="first" type="text" name="GetEmployeeByName"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<% } else { %>
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>GetEmployeeById</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input id="second" type="text" name="GetEmployeeById"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
<% } %>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input id="submit"  type="submit" name="submit" value="find" onclick="myfuntion()"></td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform the steps below:

1. Move the script in `index.jsp` file to a new JavaScript file e.g. `index.js` file and place the file in new folder e.g. `js` inside your `WebContent` folder.
2. Link `index.js` in `index.jsp` file by putting below link in the `<head>` section:

   ```
   <script language="JavaScript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/index.js">
   ```
3. Do the same in `file.jsp` file.

This way, same javascript code will be available for use in both `index.jsp` and `file.jsp` files.

Comment: can you tell me the way to get index.jsp(parent window) object in child window(file.jsp) using java svript

Comment: @ankurjadiya You can always use `window.parent.document.getElementById(elementId)` or similar functions to refer parent `DOM` elements in child window. The key here is to use `window.parent` to refer the parent.